# Emacs - How can I find the name of a command (for calling M-x <command>) for a key binding?

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

In Emacs, what are the names of the commands to:

- indent all inside the buffer (in function of which language you use) (equivalent of select all the buffer and press tab)
- move by "paragraph" (equivalent to ctrl-up and ctrl-down)
- move by word (equivalent to ctrl-right and ctrl-left)

The true is that I moved to a macbook for professional raison and these features are impossible because of the binding of OS shortcuts on ctrl+...

I already tried to find this on google but no results. I will assign new bindings to these functions in .emacs.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To help you help yourself: `C-h k` is describe key. Just press it and then your key combination and then it gives you the name and the doc for the bound elisp function.

For you it is:

- indent-region (this is usually depending on the mode)
- forward-paragraph and backward-paragraph
- backward-word and forward-word

Answer (score 1):

- `M-x indent-region`
- `M-x backward-paragraph` and `M-x forward-paragraph`
- `M-x backward-word` and `M-x forward-word`

Answer (score 1):

As said before you can use <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> to display the
documentation of the given binding. Another helpful command is the
`apropos-command` bound to <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> to find a
function when you know a part of its name.

But another really cool feature to align text is `align-regexp`
bound to <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>\</kbd>.

e.g.

```
a = 12;
baz_to_bar = 3.14;
foo = 42;
```

Select the region and then use
<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>\</kbd><kbd>=</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>

```
a          = 12;
baz_to_bar = 3.14;
foo        = 42;
```

And as its name suggests it, you can use a regular expression to
determine how emacs will align your text. Enjoy!

Comment: Not to be nitpicky, but your original example is already aligned ;) It kind of doesn't get the point across this way.

Comment: Thanks too, very useful `C-h a`. But `align-regexp` is not bound per default in `C-x \`. If you want it to `C-x \` you need to bind it.

Comment: @Bebeoix: Woa I've bound it so long ago that I didn't remember doing it.

Comment: @Daimrod: Yes that's the collateral damage when you bind something for awhile.